# Error instantiating custom class time when iostream is included

Tags: c++, oop

Here is the code:

```
//main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "time.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    time::time t;
    return 0;
}

//time.cpp
#include "time.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <stdexcept>
using namespace std;

time::time(){
    ore = minuti = secondi = 0;
} //costruttore senza argomenti

void time::setTime(int h,int m, int s){
    if(!(h<=0 && h>24)&& !(m<0 && m>60)&&!(s<=0 && s>60)){
        ore = h;
        minuti = m;
        secondi = s;
    }else{throw invalid_argument("ore,minuti e secondi non validi!!");}
}//fine del settaggio del tempo

void time::printUniversal(){
    cout << ore << ":" << minuti << ":" << secondi;
} //fine della stampa

void time::printStandard(){
    cout << ((ore == 0 || ore == 12) ? 12 : ore % 12) <<  ":" << setfill('0') << minuti << ":" << secondi << (ore < 12 ? " AM: ": " PM");
} // fine della stampa standard

//time.h
#ifndef TIME_H
#define TIME_H

class time{
public:
    time();
    void setTime(int,int,int);
    void printUniversal();
    void printStandard();
private:
    int ore;
    int minuti;
    int secondi;
};

#endif /* TIME_H */
```

Error of compiler:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
main.cpp:4:10: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘t’
     time t;
```

Comment: It is the class that I had create.

Comment: `time` is in the global namespace.

Comment: In main, do not use `time::time t;`, instead use `time t;`.  The `time` class is in the global namespace.  If you really want `time::time`, you will need to put all the `class time` still inside of a `namespace time {` ... `}`.  And that kind of same-name can get confusing.

Answer (score 0):

As [commenters have alluded to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48730288/why-do-i-get-this-error-if-i-include-iostream-library-into-the-main-the-code-is/48730330#comment84459674_48730288), your class `time` is in the global `namespace` (i.e. it's not within its own or another `namespace`), thus the correct way to reference it is with:

```
int main()
{
    time t;
}
```